# i want to deploy sklearn machine learning models and use it as a web service

Tags: machine-learning

I want to deploy skitlearn machine learning models and use them as a web service.I am using flask but it is not feasible for production ,what should i do,is there any other open source platforms available for deployment

Answer (score 0):

`Django` is the best server side framework among all frameworks I used till now.

I use pandas, numpy and all other libraries with no issues at all.